# Stop waiting for user input in java

Tags: java, multithreading, user-input

The scenario is like that: 
One thread is handling with the UI, and the second is handling the logic in the backgorund. Both are working simultaneously.

If some event occurred, and I want that the first thread will stop to wait for user command and will execute other task.

Is it possible to do it?

Comment: Do you mean something like wait() notify()?

Comment: How can you use wait() while waiting for user input?

Comment: What you really want is to block user input, which is typically done with a modal dialog, such as those created by [JOptionPane](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html).  Be very careful about using threads;  all Swing calls *must* be made in the AWT event dispatch thread, not a thread of your own creation.  See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/.

Answer (score -1):

It depends on your implementation and architecuture, but generally, you can't stop waiting for user input. For instance, calls to `System.in` are effectively translated to [system calls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call) which cannot be cancelled.